# why does Sklearn train test split returns pandas dataframe and not numpy array?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

[image: From IBM Cognitive classes]

The above fig is from ibm cognitive classes and the train test split is returning a numpy array.

[image: picture from local]

The above picture is from local and train test split is returning a pandas dataframe.

Wanted to know if there is specific reason for the same ?

sklearn version 0.19.1 on both devices.

local python 3.6.4
ibm   python 3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

The input variable y is a pandas data frame in my local and an numpy array in the ibm console.

Tiny error. Hope this helps to a beginner.